# Vertica SQL for get data in column wise

Tags: sql, vertica

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jUUt.png)Vertica SQL for get data in column wise where multiple count support in single table with different condition

```
1. select COUNT(*) as x from  WORLDPOP
2. SELECT COUNT(*) as y FROM WORLDPOP WHERE COUNTRY LIKE '%i%'
```

OP

```
x   y
10  2
```

Comment: I have requirement like daily wise count, weekly count, monthly count and yearly count of data on same table. can you provide me the query ?

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation  :

```
select count(*) as x,
       sum(case when COUNTRY LIKE '%i%' then 1 else 0 end) as y
from WORLDPOP;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for your reply. I am expecting the same query. I have requirement like daily wise count, weekly count, monthly count and yearly count of data on same table. can you provide me the query ?

Comment: @Sholk. . .  This answers your actual question if you have a new requirement, then you should ask new question with sample data & desired result instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is the way to go.  I prefer this shorter syntax which is available in Postgres-compatible databases (including Vertica):

```
select count(*) as x,
       sum( (country like '%i%')::int ) as y
from WORLDPOP;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply. I am expecting the same query. I have requirement like daily wise count, weekly count, monthly count and yearly count of data on same table. can you provide me the query ?

Comment: @Sholk . . . You should ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.